# How to pass id in update route of resource controller?

Tags: laravel, forms, laravel-5, laravel-4

Current code

```
<form action="{{route('sub-admin.update',['id' => 1])}}" id="edit-sub-admin" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
</form>
```

Current Output

```
<form action="http://localhost:8000/admin/sub-admin" id="edit-sub-admin" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
</form>
```

Expected Output

```
<form action="http://localhost:8000/admin/sub-admin/1" id="edit-sub-admin" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
</form>
```

Can anyone help me out ?

Comment: Can you show us how is your route defined in web.php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to put the `id` on array. Just use the `id` as a second parameter of `route()` function.

Example:

```
<form action="{{route('sub-admin.update',1)}}" id="edit-sub-admin" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code..

```
  <form action="{{route('sub-admin.update',['id' => 1])}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"></form>
```

OR

```
  <form action="{{route('sub-admin.update',1)}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"></form>
```

Your resource route should be like this..

```
  Route::resource('sub-admin', 'SubAdminController');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the id instead of id => some value

```
<form action="{{route('sub-admin.update',[1])}}" id="edit-sub-admin" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Answer (score 0):

//web routes

Route::post('update/{$id}', 'ControllerName@functionName');